# Perl regular expressions for finding the number of parameters of a given function

Tags: perl

Consider this line of text:

```
UINT8 function(UINT16 *num1, UINT32 num2)
```

How can I print the number of parameters for the above function using a Perl script?

Example:

The above function has two parameters. So, I need it to be printed as 2.

Comment: `say "2";`

If you intended to ask how you can have Perl figure out the number of arguments, you should probably say what language the function is supposed to be in, so people have a reasonable chance to guess at the expected syntax.

Comment: `print scalar split /,/, m/\(([^)]+)\)/; `

Comment: Yeah, trying to be too clever. How about `perl -lne 'print scalar split /,/, (m/\(([^)]+)\)/)[0]'` - that'll only work for the first declaration on each line, and only works if all the lines look the same (e.g. no line breaks).

Comment: thanks for the reply.sorry,i could not get the meaning of above regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't strip it too much. If there's one function declaration per line, then

```
echo 'UINT8 function(UINT16 *num1, UINT32 num2)' | perl -nle 'print scalar split ","'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the purpose of asking the question is to find the number of arguments in that function and i should only place the number of argument but not the entire line